# angular select box option:selected

Tags: angularjs

I have a search form where you can search for a hotel. It also asks for the number of Adults as a select box (I want it to default to 2).

To maintain state I have the search results saving as sessionStorage. I then want to pick this up and have the selected value of the number of adults that was set in the session.

Can anyone help? Can't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand correctly for your select you will need to do something like this:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

In your angular controller you can set $scope.selected to value 2 so that will be the default. You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Please let me know if you have anymore questions.